# from Linux command line, find number of lines in which a string occurs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, grep

I have a file in the location /home/someuser/sometext.txt . I want to count the number of lines in which a particular string occurs. What's the way to do that from Linux command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grep with `-c` switch is what you need:

```
grep -c "pattern" /home/someuser/sometext.txt
```

Alternate solution using awk:

```
awk '/regex/{c++}END{print c+0}' /home/someuser/sometext.txt
```

Comment: Anubhava - minor quibble, you need `END{print c+0}` in the `awk` solution to mimic `grep -c` behaviour in the case where no matches are found...thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) command.  Here's a basic [tutorial](http://www.uccs.edu/~ahitchco/grep/).  It's extremely useful for string searching in files.  It also has support for regular expressions.

It looks like you'll do something like this:

```
grep -c "mystring" /home/someuser/sometext.txt
```

The `-c` argument is short for `--count` and tells grep to print out the number of lines that contain the string.